# In drag gable view how to insert videos like youtube

Tags: android, view, draggable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IinfQ.jpg)I want to insert videos in drag-gable view like you-tube any one help me out from this problem please

Answer (score 1):

Try using this library https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel. Its designed to create draggable user interface just like Youtube.

Comment: I tried this sample bro but my video view is minimize left to right not like you-tube video view

Comment: I want minimization like you-tube

Comment: Are you didn't understand please see image in my question

Comment: In that box I have video view